# Python3 : BeautifulSoup4 not returning expected value

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to scrap some data over a website using BS4 under python 3.6.4 but the value returned is not what I am expecting:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.lacentrale.fr/listing?makesModelsCommercialNames=FERRARI&sortBy=priceAsc"
request = requests.get(link)
page = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")

price = soup.find("div", {"class" : "fieldPrice sizeC"}).text

print(price)
```

I should get "39 900 €" but the code return "47Â 880Â â¬".

NB: Even without JS, the data should be "39 900 €".

Thanks for your help !

Comment: impossible to help you without knowing the link or page content.... perhaps your html `find` is just wrong

Comment: @OferSadan The link is https://www.lacentrale.fr/listing?makesModelsCommercialNames=FERRARI&sortBy=priceAsc and why is my find wrong ?

Comment: I said perhaps, because you gave us no data to indicate otherwise... for example, adding your link to that program still doesn't work for me, your `find` returns `none`

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding declaration is wrong on this page so BeautifulSoup gets told to use the wrong encoding. You can force it to use the correct encoding like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.lacentrale.fr/listing?makesModelsCommercialNames=FERRARI&sortBy=priceAsc"
request = requests.get(link)
page = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.decode('utf-8','ignore'), "html5lib")

price = soup.find("div", {"class": "fieldPrice sizeC"}).text

print(price)
```

Outputs:

```
49 070 €
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `page.content` use `page.text`

**Ex:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.lacentrale.fr/listing?makesModelsCommercialNames=FERRARI&sortBy=priceAsc"
request = requests.get(link)
page = request.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

price = soup.find("div", {"class" : "fieldPrice sizeC"}).text

print(price)
```

- `.text` automatically decode content from the server